# Deleteing rows in a pandas dataframe if it contains a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, data-filtering

I have a list of columns in a dataframe that either contains a hashmark followed by a string or two hashmarks followed by a string. I wanted to eliminate the rows that contain only one hashmark.

`df[df["column name"].str.contains("#") == False]`

I've tried using the code above but it erased the entire column. I hoped that it would erase only the rows including only one hashmark. I do not know what to do.

Comment: Since all columns contain at least one "#", df["column name"].str.contains("#") will always be True, so df["column name"].str.contains("#") == False will always be False; thus all columns are skipped. Wouldn't  df[df["column name"].str.contains("##")] work ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
df['len']=df['column name'].str.count('#') #how many "#" expressions are in the column.

df=df[df["len"]>1]

#or one line

df=df[df['column name'].str.count('#')>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

if each of them have at least one '#' , and its either ## or #,

```
df[df["column name"].str.contains("##") == False]
```

above code will get you one #  ones.

```
df[df["column name"].str.contains("##") == True]
```

above code will eliminate #'s and get you ## ones.